# How to compile tight vnc with debug information enabled?

Tags: linux, gcc, gdb, vnc

I downloaded the tight vnc source code from its website. Now I am trying to use gdb on its executable. The debugger successfully adds breakpoints on functions but when I try to step through the function it says :

> Single Stepping until exit from function func, which has no line number information

I think it is due to the fact that the compilation wasnt done with correct flags. I am trying to search the configuration files to understand how to enable it, but haven't been able to so far. I am not acquainted with Imakefiles etc. Maybe someone who has done this previously can help ?

Using gnu GCC and GDB on an ubuntu machine

Comment: Just a note, the "g" in gcc already stands for Gnu. =)

Answer (score 0):

You should compile with the -g flag.
If you are trying to learn the code, I would recommend "-g -O0".  That will turn off the optimizer - gcc optimization can make it confusing to step through code.

Comment: I didn't know where to put -g in the makefiles. Finally I did make CDEBUGFLAGS="-ggdb" and that worked